# How do I incorporate "where [binary] is not null" in a T-SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that I need to filter rows that have a binary value and return only rows that are not null in the binary column.

When I execute this stored procedure:

```
create procedure sp_GetGraduatingStudentDataByYear
(
    @year nvarchar(4)
)
as
select * from Cohort_Graduation_Student_Data where Exp_Grad_Year = @year and Off_Track != null

go
```

I get no results.

**How can I alter this script to return the rows with a null value in the binary column?**

Comment: The subject had right answer all along

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not because it's a binary column, but because `null` in SQL should not be compared to anything. Essentially, `Off_Track != null` condition filters out all rows - all checks for `column = null` and `column != null` always evaluate to `false`.

Use `is not null` instead:

```
select *
from Cohort_Graduation_Student_Data
where Exp_Grad_Year = @year and Off_Track is not null
```